# undefined method `bson_type' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9450dbea70>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am working on rails 4 version.I am using MongoDb as a database for my project. I want to perform upload action, for that I am using "paperclip gem". I am getting the above error. Actually the error is in the Candidates controller `NoMethodError` in `CandidatesController#create_image`. Please help me to solve this issue.

If any other method is there to upload, which is compatible with mongoid, please assist me to get the solution.

This is my Candidates controller actions:

```
def profile
  @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
  @image = Image.new
end

def create_image
  @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
  @image = Image.new(new_image)
  @user = current_user
  if @image.save
    redirect_to profile_user_candidate_path(@user.id.to_s, @candidate.id.to_s)
  end
end
private
  def new_image
    params.require(:image).permit(:logo, :candidate_id)
  end
```

This is my Images controller

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @images = Images.all
  end

  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def show
    @id = params[:id]
    @image = Image.find(@id)
  end 

  def create
    @image = Image.new(params[:image])
    if @image.save
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @image.id
    end
  end

  private
    def image
      params.require(:image).permit
    end
end
```

Comment: can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: It seems like, you are using some model object's id in the code. So whenever you are using the id, make it as string. like @user.id.to_s

Comment: @Bachan Smruty : I made the changes as per your suggestion, but still no change.

Comment: can you share the code for that section, which will be easier for us.

Answer (score 1):

### Have you tried using [mongoid-paperclip](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip) ?

If you want to use mongodb and paperclip together then maybe using [mongoid-paperclip](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip) will solve all your problems.

### Other ways you can help us answer

- It's not clear what the name of the controller is. Please add the whole class so the names are clear.
- It's not clear what line you are getting the error on. You should be able to tell us that.
- It's always more clear if you paste the whole error message here. Even a little bit of stack trace.
- Tell us what the user is trying to do when you get the error.
- Also giving us your routes might be helpful

Comment: I already got solution for my problem. This error was  due to missing of "has_attached_file.rb" in "initializers". I used "mongoid-paperclip" gem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the params weren't permitted first. You should do `new_params = params.permit!.to_h` first and then use that.

Better yet, permit only what you need.